# Валидность кода JS

Tags: javascript

Почему подобная конструкция не проходит проверку? 
Подскажите, в чем ошибка.

> В этом задании вам нужно написать программу, которая будет определять является ли число палиндромом.
>
> Алгоритм такой: нужно записать изначальное число задом наперёд и сравнить этот вариант с изначальным. Если оба числа равны — перед нами палиндром.

```js
var poly = 1221;
var ylop = 0;
var isPalindrome = false;
var biba = 0;


while (isPalindrome = false) {
    biba = poly % 10;
    ylop = Math.round(poly / 10) + biba.toString();
    if (ylop == poly) {
        isPalindrome = true;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: мне кажется или ваш цикл ни разу не выполнится, потому что вы `isPalindrom = false` всегда вернет `false`?

Comment: и что за переменная `biba`?))) смешное название

Comment: и почему вы не воспользовались подсказкой `нужно записать изначальное число задом наперёд и сравнить этот вариант с изначальным.` ваш кода делает что-то другое

Comment: Помимо всего вышесказанного, вы сейчас берете число `1221`, разбиваете на два числа `122` и `1`, после чего их снова склеиваете в `1221`. Это точно не то, чего от вас требует задание. В общем исправьте пока `isPalindrome == false` и попробуйте решить дальше самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если следовать описанию, которое используется в задаче, то код должен выглядеть вот так:

```js
const poly = 13231;
const notPoly = 45162;

const isPolyndrom = n => {
 return n.toString() === n.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
}

// С учетом что проверяются только целые числа
console.log(isPolyndrom(poly));
console.log(isPolyndrom(notPoly));
```

Но это не совсем оптимальный способ, потому что мы несколько раз проходимся по всем цифрам в числе (`split`, `reverse`, `join`). 
Есть более оптимальный способ:

```js
const poly = 13231;
const notPoly = 45162;

const isPolyndrom = n => {
  const nAsString = n.toString();
  const length = nAsString.length;
  const lastIndex = length - 1;
  
  for(let i = 0; i <= Math.round(length / 2); i++) {
    // Если противоположные элементы относительно центра не равны, то не полиндром
    if (nAsString[i] !== nAsString[lastIndex -i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

// С учетом что проверяются только целые числа
console.log(isPolyndrom(poly));
console.log(isPolyndrom(notPoly));
```

Преимущество в том, что используется только один цикл